# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in StoreController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm on page 239 of "agile web development with rails 4th ed." I have one tab in my browser pointing to localhost:3000 and it works fine. Another tab is pointing to "depot.thefonso.com" and I get this error:

"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in StoreController#index"

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: products: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY title

Rails.root: /Users/gideon/Desktop/Rails_work/depot

...

app/controllers/store_controller.rb:7:in `index'

here is line 7 in store_controller.rb....

```
  @products = Product.all
```

Can any guru point me in the right direction?

HERE IS MY database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
  development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
 test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run `cap deploy:migrations` (as instructed on page 237)?

From your symptoms, your database doesn't have the Product table defined.  I'll also note that you didn't change from sqlite3 to mysql.

Please run the following commands on your two machines and compare the schemas produced:

```
sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 .schema

sqlite3 db/production.db .schema
```

Comment: Hmm, I've got the pdf version, and "cap deploy:migrations" isn't listed from the beginning of this chapter (235) up to pag 240...no mention of it. curious.

Comment: If you are going by PDF page numbers, then simply keep going!  :-)  The next step is to set up your database.

Comment: I'm now on page 142(pdf version) I'm at the "Deploy Remotely with Capistrano". After using 'mysql2','0.2.7' in my gemfile and changing mysql to mysql2 in database.yml I was able to run the command "rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="production"" without error. almost...it did tell me that "depot_production already exists" but proceeded as indicated on  page 241 of the pdf text. Just for kicks I ran the two commands you mentioned for the schema. "sqlite3 db/production.db .schema" produced nothing...just a blank. While the first command produced output.

Comment: AH HA! I see the command "cap deploy migrations" (oh course inside capistrano section). OK, let me finish reading this next section maybe this explains everything for me...I hope so.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Rails can't find the table so if it works locally it's most likely only a configuration problem.

Check your `database.yml` configuration for the application running on `depot.thefonso.com`. It's most likely looking for a database on `localhost` and can't find it on your remote server.

Comment: Hmm, that's the thing the physical files are located in the same location right now. I'm at Iteration K1 "deployment" the text doesn't indicate if this error is normal for where I am or not. The text actually implies that the application should be working fine. I will post the internals for my database.yml: